# Let $x$, $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, find all the complex numbers $z=a+bi$ satisfying $|z+x|$ $= y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $x$, $y$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$, find all the complex numbers $z=a+bi$ satisfying $|z+x|$ $= y$.

Because $x$ and $y$ are real numbers and $z=a+bi$ then, $|z+x|=|(a+x)+bi|=\sqrt{(x+a)^{2}+b^{2}}$.

Therefore, $\sqrt{(x+a)^{2}+b^{2}}=y$. So, $(x+a)^{2}+b^{2}=y^{2}$ $\implies$ $x^{2}+2ax+a^{2}+b^{2}=y^{2}$

The problem I now find myself with is that the only solution of $z$ I'm able to provide is in terms of itself (solving for $a$ gives me an expression with $b$ and vice versa), I believe I've done something wrong or there's something I'm missing.

I've also tried giving a geometrical interpretation of the problem in order to solve it, but I've come empty handed.

A hint or and explanation of where I'm doing something wrong would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely on the right lines, in fact you're pretty much there. An answer in terms of $a$ or $b$ is perfectly acceptable. Solving for $b$ you obtain

$$b = \pm\sqrt{y^2 -(x+a)^2} $$

and then you can just substitute this back into your general form $z= a+bi$. So for any pair of real numbers $x$ and $y$, complex numbers of the form

$$ z = a \pm i\sqrt{y^2 -(x+a)^2 }$$

satisfy the desired property that $|z + x| = y$. In other words, given $x$ and $y$ then plugging any real number $a$ into the formula above gives you a valid complex number. Hope this helps!